# How to resolve a BootBlock BIOS and BIOS ROM checksum error?

Tags: bios, desktop-computer

I am having a `BIOS ROM checksum error` when I start my desktop. Here's a screenshot:

[image: this picture is what the screen looks like]

My desktop is an HP Pavilion t3530.tr Desktop PC running Windows 7. I did a search and found [this](http://www.birdjanitor.com/bootblock.html) and [this](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626%201302360447926%2028353475&threadId=1111210), but the problem is that I cannot get to a DOS command line because of the error. I also downloaded the latest BIOS update, burned it onto a CD, and inserted it into my computer, but it only showed **PASS**. What else could I try?

Comment: What happened immediately before this error appeared?  Were you flashing your BIOS before it happened, or did you download the BIOS to try and fix the problem?

Comment: @Matt Jenkins seriously nothing happened just before the error, I turned the computer on and this error come out. I downloaded the latest BIOS and burned it in a cd put it into the computer but my desktop couldnt load it so i was able to do nothing else. All ı can do is press enter and it gives me just a buzz with "INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER".

Comment: how can i reflash the BIOS? maybe it helps.

Comment: Since you're being asked for a "system disk", you could try using a MS-DOS [boot floppy disk](http://www.bootdisk.com/). The `AWDFLASH.EXE` tool is written for MS-DOS, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You need a specialist to reflash the BIOS for you, best to just go for the RMA route.